# Redirecting hardcoded links

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, hosts

I have a website with all hardcoded links http://www.example.com

I have done a redesign of the web site and want to test to make sure all of the links are working.  Can I put all of my files at http://testing.example.com and see if my links are working?

I was able to edit my hosts file:
My IP address testing.example.com www.testing.example.com

However, links in the file at testing.example.com still point to http://www.example.com

Any ideas?

#

Rewriting the question
The links in my html file are pointing to http://www.example.com/contact/, http://www.example.com/products/ etc.  They're not relative links.

I want to test my html file before going live somehow without having to change the absolute links above.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking. Instead of all that "example.com" stuff, post what you have, what you are trying to do, what you tried so far, what is wrong with that and how we can help you. _Be specific_.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry, it wasn't more clear.  I added 2 sentences at the bottom..go off of that instead. Thanks

Comment: No idea why one would want to do that, but anyway: you first need to manipulate the name resolution for "example.com", so that the subdomains "testing.example.com" and "www.example.com" are resolved to the same ip address, either by CNAME or by a wildcard A record. Then you need to configure "testing.example.com" as additional host in your http server. It might be that you have to create some rewriting rule for internal redirects, but yu might also get along without, depending on the details of your setup. Sorry, as said: without any specific  information only a vague answer is possible.